# VBS RegExp Error - Pulling text from beginning of line

Tags: regex, vbscript

I need to pull the first 3 to 13 characters out of a string, starting at the beginning of the line and ending at the first encounter of whitespace.

The following code I cannot get to work. I often get an "Invalid Procedure" error. Changing the pattern sometimes makes the error go away, but it never results in the match that I need.

Please Help.

EDIT: I found this pattern "/[^ ]*/" which should do what I want (I think), but now when I execute the code I get an error at line strOut = match.SubMatches(0). Any idea why?

```
    ' Set the pattern to find the data we would like to test; 
re_Name.Pattern = "^xe\-1/1/1"
re_Name.IgnoreCase = True
re_Name.Multiline = True

vLines = Split(strNames, vbcrlf)
For Each strLine in vLines
Set matches = re_Name.Execute(strLine)
    For Each match in matches
        strOut = match.SubMatches(0)
        MsgBox strOut
        Next
    Next
```

Examples of what I am searching for:

```
xe-0/1/1
xe-0/3/2.0
ge-11/2/1
ae0
ae0.3156
```

Example of what it might like in context:

```
xe-0/0/0        up    up   xxxxxxxxxxJxx0/0xToxBBxxx1 x;
ae0.202         up    up   ;xxxxxx1;xxxxxxxxixxxxx 
ge-11/3/0.0     up    down Rxxxxxxx RESERVEDing
```

Comment: I found this pattern "/[^ ]*/" which should do what I want (I think), but now when I execute the code I get an error at line strOut = match.SubMatches(0). Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `strOut = match.SubMatches(0)` should be `strOut = match.Value` as you're not capturing any submatches because you're not using brackets to capture anything.

If you just want to match characters up to the first space you could use

```
 re_Name.Pattern = "^\S+"
```

`\S` matchs any non-space character.

Answer (score 1):

Your Regexp lacks capturing () to make Submatches possible. Using Split on space would probably a less risky approach.